# Why is the latest Webb discovery of early-age universe considered so important?

Tags: cosmology, james-webb-space-telescope, cosmological-inflation

The past week, news were flooding of an unexpected discovery of James Webb Space Telescope. In many articles it is mentioned that cosmologists cannot explain the formation of galaxies of this magnitude on that stage of development of the universe.

My question is this:
What kind of evidence did cosmologists have to support a theory that an earlier, more densely packed with matter universe, where galactic collisions and mergers were more frequent, would wield smaller galaxies ?

Sources:
https://edition.cnn.com/2023/02/22/world/webb-telescope-massive-early-galaxies-scn/index.html

https://www.space.com/james-webb-space-telescope-giant-distant-galaxies-surprise

https://www.colorado.edu/today/2023/02/22/webb-telescope-spots-super-old-massive-galaxies-shouldnt-exist

https://www.euronews.com/next/2023/02/23/scientists-mind-blown-after-james-webb-telescope-finds-massive-universe-breaker-galaxies

Comment: The predominant idea is that small galaxies merge to form large galaxies. Obviously the small galaxies come first.

Comment: You might want to correct your title. "huge early-age universe" is not what you are asking about.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape You are right. I had a different phrase in mind while typing and changed the expression during typing without revising it.